# Why the same code outside the decorator works and not inside?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This code in `models.py` works:

```
f = auto_history()
f.history_connect_signals(Product, Product_History)
```

but this code doesn't work, in fact in that code doesn't do anything:

```
def auto_signals(_sender):
    def history_signals(_history):
        print str(_sender)+str(_history)
        f = auto_history()
        f.history_connect_signals(_sender, _history)
        return _history
    return history_signals
```

this is the instantiated class:

```
class auto_history(object):
    def class_save(self, sender, instance, signal,created=False, *args, **kwargs):
        h = self.history_class()
        h.save_history(_signal=signal, _created=created, _instance=instance)

    def history_connect_signals(self, _product, _history):
        self.history_class = _history
        post_save.connect(self.class_save, sender=_product)    
        pre_delete.connect(self.class_save, sender=_product)

    def __call__(self, _sender, _history):
        self.history_connect_signals(_sender, _history)
```

I use this decorator to connect a model with a class as sender to a auto_history class to save any change.

```
@auto_signals(Product)
class Product_History(Model_History, ProductBase):
```

Comment: Does the print in `auto_signals` work? Is `auto_history.history_connect_signals()` called? If so, can you print the args there?

Comment: Yes auto_signals and history_connect_signals are called, only don't work the prints in class_save because never is call